# How to select children elements but only one level deep with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div200">
            <div id="div3" class="b">       
            </div>
            <div id="div300">
                <div id="div4" class="b">
                     <div id="div5"> 
                        <div id="div6" class="b">
                        </div>            
                     </div>
                </div>
            <div>
        <div>
    <div>
</div>
```

I need a way to find the children (deep) of an element that are of class "b" but not those that are nested inside a matched element.

**Test cases:**

This is what I need:

Case 1:

```
$("#div1").some_jquery_syntax(".b")
Should return:
div3, div4
```

Case 2:

```
$("#div5").some_jquery_syntax(".b")
Should return:
div6
```

Note that the hard part is that I have have to skip div2 when starting from div1. So I can't just use `$("#div1").find("> .b")`.

**My attempts:**

I tried this:

```
$("#div1").find(".b")
[<div id="div3" class="b"></div>, <div id="div4" class="b"></div>, <div id="div5" class="b"></div>]
```

Not good: I don't want div5 because it is nested inside div4.

I tried this:

```
$("#div0").find(".b").not(".b .b")
[<div id="div3" class="b"></div>, <div id="div4" class="b"></div>]
```

Which is ok when starting with div0, but it does not work stating from div4:

```
$("#div5").find(".b").not(".b .b")
[]
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Too many `div4`s.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I broke it while formatting it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Find the immediate grand-children:

```
​$("#div1").children().children(".b");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/Dy6GJ/

If you don't know how deep to go, but want all `.b` not within a `.b`, use a filter while respecting parent limitations. You could use the `.parentsUntil` method:

```
var parent = "#div1";
$(".b", parent).filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parentsUntil(parent, ".b").length;
}).css("border", "1px solid red");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/Dy6GJ/3/

Comment: @Sly Then base your select off of `#div2`. You cannot ask for *one-level deep* when they're not in the next level.

Comment: No I can't start at div2. I need to find the first deep child but not those below.

Comment: @Sly Then use two calls to `.children()` to get the grandchildren.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how deep it is going to be. All I know is it is somewhere below.

Comment: @Sly Posted another solution in the answer above.

Comment: Yep `Dy6GJ/3/` works perfectly. You linked `Dy6GJ/2/` in your answer so I did not try the right code.

Comment: I edited my question and made the html a bit more complex (see div200, div300). This way your solution with parentsUntil still works perfectly, but not the one with siblings.

Comment: There is an easier solution than using filter and parentsUntil... Just use `$("#div4").find(".b").not("#div4 .b .b")`

Answer (score 5):

General (when only class can be guaranteed):

```
$("#div1").find(".b:not(.b .b)")
```

As described (likely faster than general, though not tested):

```
$("#div1").find("div.b:not(div.b div.b)")
```

"All .b which are not descendants of .b"

Answer (score 2):

You were not far from the fastest solution, the problem with

```
$("#div5").find(".b").not(".b .b")
```

Is that the ***`.not`*** is not relative to your initial selector (eg: *`#div5`*) and since there is a *`.b`* parent to *`#div6`* in the DOM tree it will be excluded (the parent being *`#div4`*)

The solution is then to make your ***`.not`*** relative to your selector

This will correctly select *`#div6`* :

```
$("#div4").find(".b").not("#div4 .b .b")
```

This will correctly select *`#div3`* and *`#div4`* :

```
$("#div1").find(".b").not("#div1 .b .b")
```

You might also be interested in [this recursive iterator function](http://jsfiddle.net/mpauzt6h/3/)

It will call a callback function with the current element and depth as parameter, the recursion can be done ascendant or descendant using the asc parameter and you can also specify a max depth of recursion

In desc mode if your callback return false the iteration immediatly stops